# invalide date after converting epoch time vue.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, vue.js, epoch

Im trying to make a table with vue.js and one of the row is supposed to print a date i receive in epoch time. but fail to convert it in a readable date and just get "invalide date" printed  on my browser.

Here is how i convert it

```
  var sec = 1588351494;
    var tmp =new Date(0);
    tmp.setUTCDate(sec);
    var res= tmp;
```

her is how it's made to be able to be called as a vue.js object

```
      return {
        tableData: [
          {
            uid: '01020304050607',
            lastReadDate: res,
          },
        ]
      }
```

And then i simply print it in my html page doing this, which print the "invalide date" in the row.

```
          <td>
            {{row.lastReadDate }}
          </td>
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant `tmp.setUTCSeconds(sec)`

Comment: dang, thank you. it print the date. how can i change the format of it, like only printing  DD//MM//YYYY?

Comment: You can call `getDate()`, `getMonth()` and `getYear()` on the `Date` object to retrieve those sections and glue them back together.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var sec = 1588351494;
var res =new Date(sec * 1000);  // multiply seconds with 1000 to convert it to ms.
```

Check the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vf74h5n0/4/

To format date in "DD/MM/YYYY" you can use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/).

```js
var date = new Date(1588351494 * 1000);
moment(date).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
```

Here is a example https://jsfiddle.net/vf74h5n0/5/